# How do I debug requirements for Google-Mobile-Ads-Sdk?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I'm getting undefined architecture error. For other frameworks I can read in documentation what is required.

For Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, their sample app has no libraries linked.

How do I debug what frameworks are needed?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainScene.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainScene.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainScene.o
  "_kGADSimulatorID", referenced from:
      -[MainScene init] in MainScene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you remember the solution to this?

Comment: @DanielEspina when in doubt, do a fresh install of EVERYTHING. Make sure your Xcode is up to date and start a new project, go from there.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that Firebase Analytics now require a Depolyment Target of 11.0. Since I had them connected with my AdMob ads it caused this linker error.

Comment: On github CocoaPods for Google Mobile Ads SDK you can check the json files for each version to ensure you've added all dependencies: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK